# FTP.changeWorkingDirectory not working when tried to FTP from Server

Tags: java, linux, ftp

I am using FTP to transfer files from India to Germany.
When I try to transfer the files from my PC, everything works fine.
But, when I deploy the application in the Linux server in India and try to transfer,
the code *ftp.changeWorkingDirectory("/")* gives 'false' result.
However, I can do this transfer to another FTP setup in India.
The Server in Germany seems to have all the rights required when I check using FTPClient.
What may be the reason? What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Which FTPClient (which library)? Can you show your code?

Comment: if (ftp.changeWorkingDirectory("/")) {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry.. 
It was was escape sequence error..
As it is different in Windows and Linux Systems.
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You probably just do not have any permissions to visit the directory `/` (root).  Try the same with a directory you definitely have access to.

Comment: That may not be the case.. I can transfer the files from my PC using the same code..

Comment: Another point: I had to add the System name before the username to connect to the FTP Server. like : FW-ZOWS2\<username>.

Answer (score 0):

If it works locally but not remotely, usually the problem is that you are not using PASSIVE mode in a situation where the server cannot connect back to you.

But here you already get an error when doing `changeWorkingDirectory`. Can you do `ftp.cwd("/")` (which returns an `int`, the FTP reply code) and show which error code you get?

Comment: Error code is 530. I know its about log-in. But I can login from my PC using same details.

Comment: Did you check the result of the login method, was it true or false? If it was false, what does ftp.getReply() return just after the login() call?

Comment: Also, I am checking the boolean values. If the login fails, the ftp.cwd code won't execute. But, this code is executing, which means login is a success. Any other reason for error code 530?